# Existence of associated primes of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Is it true that if $M\neq0$ is Noetherian then $\mbox{Ass}(M)\neq\emptyset$ and $|\mbox{Ass}(M)|<\infty$ ? Many books (e.g. Eisenbud, Atiyah) seem to require the ring to be Noetherian, as well, but I have a convincing proof which requires only the module to be Noetherian (based on proofs from Injective Modules, by Sharpe & Vamos). But it's hard to ignore Eisenbud and Atiyah. Does anyone have any opinion on this?

p.s. Here by associated primes I mean prime annihilators of elements of the module, not those primes related to primary decomposition of the zero submodule. I understand that they coincide if the ring is Noetherian.

Comment: Exercise:If $M$ is Noetherian, then $R/\mathrm{ann}(M)$ is a Noetherian ring! Then we may assume $R$ is Noetherian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true for a Noetherian module. Please see page 109 in the following notes.
http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/614F10/614.pdf